# Mixed flight / bus search engine?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, buses, flight-search-engines

Some months ago I came across a good website that offers to search and plan your travel with mixes way of transportation... Like for example you have to plan a mixed way, like flight and bus, similar to www.fromatob.com?

Answer (score 7):

[rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) is a  multimodal transport search engine that mixed flight, bus and ship.

Compared to fromatob it search much faster and cover bigger area. It also show the route of each option in the map.

(the upper one is exeter, uk-Hong kong searched by fromatob and the lower is same route searched by rome2rio)

[image]

Comment: Rome2Rio lets any place be an endpoint.  fromatob just told me I have to "select one of the suggested locations" (when there are no suggestions).  On the other hand, Rome2Rio has an irritating habit of assuming I didn't mean what I typed and changing it to someplace else in another country.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to travel within one country in Europe you can often use the train planner to get a combination of train and bus, like the [Bahn](http://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/index.shtml) site for Germany and [Belgianrail](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/Default.aspx) for Belgium.
In the UK you can use [traveline](http://www.traveline.info/) for train, coach and buses, I am not sure about flights but it might work.

Non of those keeps being that helpful when crossing national borders.

Comment: thanks! do you have some suggestions about portugal and spain?